# Erro Access restriction: The type is not accessible

Tags: java

Estou tentando desenvolver uma tela simples em java utilizando `JFrame` mas no meu eclipse está mostrando uma mensagem no `JFrame`.

> Access restriction: The construction JFrame(String) is not accessible
>   due to restriction on required library
>   usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
>
> Access restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible due to
>   restriction on required library
>   usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar

Meu eclipse é no Linux Mint 18.3 (Sylvia)

Meu código:

```
package view;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TelaInicial {


    private void construirJanela(){

        JFrame janela = new JFrame("Janela");
        janela.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Meu java está assim:

```
carlos@carlos /usr/lib/jvm $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Voce se certificou de que tem a JRE na mesma arquitetura do eclipse?

Comment: instalei pelo apt-get install eclipse

Comment: Tente isto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174607/5524514

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado! Pode adicionar resposta

Comment: Pode responder voce mesmo, uma vez que a solucao nao foi minha, e sim do SOEn :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme [esta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174607/5524514), você pode tentar o seguinte:

- Clique com o botão direito no projeto e selecione *Properties*;
- Vá até "*Java Build Path*" e remova a lib "*JRE System Library*";
- Readicione-a clicando em "*Add Library*".

O motivo provável desse erro deve ser conflitos de classes com nomes semelhantes em diferentes bibliotecas adicionadas no projeto. Readicionando  jar do sistema, você reordena este jar para o topo da lista a ser consultado quando for importar uma classe com nome semelhante.